# Crystal 8.5 has ChangeDatabaseDriver function - how to do the same in Delphi Code?

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, delphi-7, crystal-reports-8.5

We have a very large number of reports created to use the BDE driver.

Our application has been migrated to a database that can be accessed via ODBC.  All Tables, Fields etc. are comparable.

As there are many Crystal reports in existence (including some developed by/for third parties) we would like to be able to change the Database Driver used by a report on the fly at runtime, from our Delphi-7 application.

In Crystal there is a menu Item to change the driver for a report ( - and if manually converting a report this does exactly what we want.

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's a ConvertDriver method for the TCrpeTables class but not sure if that is of use or not?

Answer (score 0):

In my CrystalReportWrapper I send the connectionstring of my TAdoConnection, to change the connection in the report of crystal report.

```
<TCrpe>.Connect.ServerName:= AServerName;
<TCrpe>.Connect.UserID:= AUserID;
<TCrpe>.Connect.Password:= APassWord;
<TCrpe>.Connect.DatabaseName:= ADataBaseName;
<TCrpe>.Connect.Propagate := False;
<TCrpe>.Connect.Test;
```